# What is the view used in the sample video

Tags: android, view, slide

I found this view in the PayTm app , i would like to implement something similar.
If it is a pre existing view which one is it. Or could you give any suggestions on how to implement such a view.

This is the [video](https://www.box.com/s/3i3xsmd5khbvtrqc1dg5)

Comment: It's a `SlidingMenu` - have a look at this opensource library: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Comment: I got that, thanks a lot.